# How to change kendoGrid table title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a small application using "kendo-grid" to display the rows in a table. The data is filtered by selecting an item from a `<select>`. As the data type, which is shown, while filtering changes, I was wondering how I can change the titles of the table rows. I was thinking of using some instructions as jQuery `$().html` . However, maybe you can meet other better way to do this. thanks.[image]

BTW: Sorry for the ".jpg-made-in-paint". I'm desperate.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer:**

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/how-do-you-change-the-column-header-text-in-javascript.aspx

Essentially use jQuery to find the element and update it.

Something like this:

```
$("#grid thead tr th [data-field=CustomerNumber]").html("NewTitle")
```

Comment: Don't you think that he is trying to change the title once it is already set?

Comment: Does that change the validity of my answer ? Setting the title before it's set and setting the title after it's been set, seems like the same thing to me...

Comment: Either I did not understand how you plan to modify the value or yes, it changes the validity. Check this code http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nLn5b/ and tell me what is wrong and why it doesn't work changing the title.

Comment: I see your point. There another less elegant way to do this with jquery I'll find the link